# 4.2.2 stuck in an db upgrade loop with "Call to undefined method wpdb::get_col_length()"

Tags: errors, upgrade

During an automatic upgrade to 4.2.2 I am getting a blank screen on upgrading the database and the following error in the php.log:

```
[Mon Jun 29 08:48:10 2015] [error] [client 127.12.209.129] PHP Fatal error:  
Call to undefined method wpdb::get_col_length() in 
/var/lib/openshift/site/app-root/runtime/repo/php/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php 
on line 1461, 
referer: http://example.com/wp-admin/upgrade.php?_wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2F
```

The public front of the site works fine but I cannot login to the admin area without it trying to run the database upgrade and giving me a blank screen.

Trying a manual upgrade does not fix the problem. Things are stuck in a loop trying to upgrade the database and not being able to find `wpdb::get_col_length()` in the functions included into the upgrade code.

Answer (score 0):

I checked in mysql and the type of the column it was looking for is `text` and in version 5.1 of MySQL that I am using the size is 65,535 so I replaced line 1461 which was giving error with the following hardcoded size:

```
        $content_length = array(
                        'type'   => 'byte',
                        'length' => 65535,
                );
```

After that the upgrade completed fine and the site is healthy.